# Pull/Read exact no. of messages from azure service bus queue

Tags: c#, .net, azure, message-queue, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to read exact no. of messages at a time from service bus queue.

We are using below code base in C#,

```
await using var client = new ServiceBusClient("myconnection");   
ServiceBusReceiver receiver = client.CreateReceiver("myqueue") 
var receivedMessages = await receiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(100);
```

I learned that, this method does not guarantee exact no. of message to read/pull. i.e. If we ask to read 100 message per execution, it will return any random count < 100.
I tried different ways like configuring PrefetchCount but no luck.

Is there a way in C# SDK? or May be some native mechanism.

Comment: *If we ask to read 100 message per execution, it will return any random count < 100*: that is because it defines [the maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiver.receivemessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_ServiceBus_ServiceBusReceiver_ReceiveMessagesAsync_System_Int32_System_Nullable_System_TimeSpan__System_Threading_CancellationToken_) count of messages to read.

Comment: Are you sure there even are 100 messages in the queue ?

Comment: @PeterBons obviously sir, there are tons of messages.

Comment: Do you really need to have batches of 100 messages? If so, just use `ReceiveMessagesAsync` and fill up your own buffer up to 100 messages.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [***Microsoft Documentation:-***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk#development-and-testing-features)

> `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` and `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` does not
> expose the batch functionality like to read n no.of message at a time .

To use [**`batch`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient.receivebatchasync?view=azure-dotnet) we can use `Microsft.Azure.servicebus` sdk which is supported .

For example to receive set of messages in batch processing:

```
public 

System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage>> ReceiveBatchAsync (int messageCount);
```

For more information Please refer this [***MS Q&A***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/92901/how-to-receive-n-number-of-messages-at-time-from-a.html) as suggested by [***MayankBargali-MSFT***](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/1099057/mayankbargali-msft.html)